# Função lambda para dict de dict - Python

Tags: python, json, expressões-lambda, filter

Eu gostaria de saber se existe a possibilidade de usar o `filter` com uma função `lambda` para selecionar um `conjunto de dados` de um `array de J
SON` no `Python`.

Exemplo: Eu tenho o seguinte `JSON` já como `dict` no `Python`, segue a estrutura.  E gostaria de `filtrar` os `dict's internos` que são do tipo `'event' == 'a'`.

```
{'events': [{'event':'a', ...},{'event':'b',...},{'event':'a'...}]}
```

Eu gostaria de algo como:

```
list_a = dict(filter(lambda x: [events][][x] == 'a', data_json.items()))
```

Eu não estou conseguindo enxergar uma maneira de `filtrar` os dicionários mais internos desse `'events'`.

Comment: O que deseja como retorno desse `filter` ???

Comment: Eu gostaria de obter todo o conteúdo do array de 'events' que possuem o 'event' = 'a' .

Comment: Somente utlizando `lambda` ?

Comment: Sim, essa é a dúvida.

Comment: Tente f = filter(lambda x: x['event'] == 'a',dic['events'])

Answer (score 1):

A geração *inline* de dicionários é feita através de uma [compreensão de dicionário](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/#id7):

```
data_json = {'events': [{'event':'a', 'foo': 'bar'}, {'event':'b', 'foo': 'baz'}, {'event':'a', 'foo': 'bax'}]}
dict_a = {key: list(filter(lambda x: x['event'] == 'a', lst)) for key, lst in data_json.items()}
print(dict_a)
# {'events': [{'event': 'a', 'foo': 'bar'}, {'event': 'a', 'foo': 'bax'}]}
```

Você pode também usar uma compreensão de lista no lugar do `filter`:

```
data_json = {'events': [{'event':'a', 'foo': 'bar'}, {'event':'b', 'foo': 'baz'}, {'event':'a', 'foo': 'bax'}]}
dict_a = {key: [item for item in lst if item['event'] == 'a'] for key, lst in data_json.items()}
print(dict_a)
# {'events': [{'event': 'a', 'foo': 'bar'}, {'event': 'a', 'foo': 'bax'}]}
```